# Validating rails database design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

Is there any tool that would automatically check database design (foreign keys, indexes, not null and so on), and give an advise what could be improved?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite Manager as firefox plugin gives the database view. Its a pretty good tool! & easy to use.

Comment: It lets you manage any SQLite database on your computer. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Comment: hm... I evaluate my db using SQLITE Manager tool & do the manual unit testing or functional testing using RSpec